# Theme Choosing on the basis of a certain API value

Tags: webpack, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am working on a front-end project. My task is to receive an API token, then conditionally choose a theme (CSS file) for different API values.
now I have some plans,

```
1. doing something with package.json
2. using sass/compass
3. using webpack
```

According to project owner , I am not allowed to use less or sass. Is there any way to do so? I am using Nuxt.js .

N.B: what is have to do within the entry point of project, i.e. before loading the whole project

Comment: This is more of a ui problem than a webpack problem i would say. If you were to use react, i would suggest you using the context api or something like that, but for vue, i have no idea if there is such thing.

Comment: nuxt also has context . its in layout.In fact they want me to change the whole site.

Comment: just fyi -> nuxt use a webpack xD So you already using it, although it not relevant to the question itself

Comment: lol yes. actually how could i do it before site is even loading?? i think its a nonsense idea

Comment: Depends, if you mean one theme uses vuetify, one bootstrap, etc etc.. then I don't think it can be done unless you include all the different themes and frameworks which would be inefficient and bloated when bundled. But if its a simple case of changing basic styling then yeah thats simple you would use beforeMount to apply which style/themes in the layout, or conditionally use different layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did this simple task and worked like charm:

```
data(){
     return{
       api_value:0
     }
   },
   beforeCreate(){
     axios.get('my-api-link)
         .then(response=>{
          this.api_value = response.data.api_value
      })

   },

     computed:{
         inject_theme(){
           if(this.api_value ==1)
             return '/theme/dark.css'
           else if (this.api_value ==2)
              return '/theme/dark.1.css'
           else if (this.api_value ==3)
              return '/theme/dark.2.css'
         }
       },

   head () {
    return {
      title: this.title,
      meta: [
        { hid: 'description', name: this.inject_theme, content: 'My custom description' }
      ],
      link:[
        {rel:'stylesheet',href:this.inject_theme}
      ] 
    }
  }
```